# Distribute full shortcut as part of an iOS app

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am trying to distribute a Siri Shortcut with an iOS app. However, after bundling the shortcut with the app, I did not find a way satisfying way to get it installed.

How can I install a shortcut from my iOS app (in an Apple-approved way) besides an iCloud link?

Note that I am NOT talking about donating single INIntents here. I want to include a complex shortcut that includes branching, looping, etc.

What I've tried so far: My shortcut has been exported as a .shortcut file, which I included as a resource in my app bundle.

1. I was unable to install the shortcut through UIActivityViewController, as there is no "Add to Shortcuts" option. I can store the shortcut in Files and let the user open it from there, but this is not acceptable UX.
2. I was unable to open the shortcut with the shortcuts app directly using `UIApplication.shared.open(fileUrlOfShortcut)`
3. I was unable to identify a URL scheme of the shortcuts app, which would allow me to add a shortcut.

Comment: The iCloud link is probably your best bet. If I was in your shoes, I'd fetch the URL from a server in case I need to make any changes to the shortcut. Why are you against the link method?